# Get php array from another server

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

I have a php file list.php

```
<?php
$arr=array('444','555');
echo var_export($arr);
?>
```

Now I want to get the array from another php script using file_get_contents.
how can be this achieved ? I dont want to use sessions. **The two scripts are on different servers.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) the array or use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to encode the array in JSON. Then, in the other PHP script, you would use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) or [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to get the string back into an array.

Example, using `serialize()`:

**In a.php** (on server A)

```
$array = array( "foo" => 5, "bar" => "baz");
file_put_contents( 'array.txt', serialize( $array));
```

**In b.php** (on server B)

```
$string = file_get_contents( 'http://www.otherserver.com/array.txt');
$array = unserialize( $string);
var_dump( $array); // This will print the original array
```

---

You can also output the string from a PHP script, instead of saving it to a file, like so:

**In a.php** (on server A)

```
$array = array( "foo" => 5, "bar" => "baz");
echo serialize( $array); exit;
```

**In b.php** (on server B)

```
$string = file_get_contents( 'http://www.otherserver.com/a.php');
$array = unserialize( $string);
var_dump( $array); // This will print the original array
```

Comment: Could you explain me that using a code example ? I actually tried both the ways you are mentioning. I get an error :php unserialize Error at offset 0. and for json the result i am getting is NULL.

Comment: @ASHUTOSH - Already added a simple example. Let me know if that doesn't work for you

Comment: Thanks nick. Earlier I user following code: In a.php  <?php
$arr=array('444','555');
echo serialize($arr);
?>                                                                 and in b.php <?php
  
  $data=file_get_contents('http://fbapps.net23.net/fbag/tmp.php');
  $arr=unserialize( $string);
  var_dump($arr);
?>  Was i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As a little extension to nickb's answer:

Script1

```
$arr=array('444','555');
file_put_contents("data.txt", serialize($arr));
```

Script 2

```
$arr = unserialize(file_get_contents("data.txt"));
```

Should work!

Edit: oh well, nick added an example himself :)